# Pass a tuple in to a helper class

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

I need some help implementing a design for my program. So I have a tuple with everything I want in it, created from this call

```
auto t1 = getMyTuple();
```

But I want to make a helper class so that I can overload the << operator, so that when I call

```
std::cout << my_tuple_helper;
```

it will print out each thing.

I have a helper class but I dont know how to get t1 into it.. it looks something like

```
template<typename... Args>
class my_tuple_helper
{
  public:
  std::tuple<Args...> my_tup;

  my_tuple_helper(std::tuple<Args... t)
  {
    my_tup = t;
  }

 //or

  my_tuple_helper(Args... args)
  {
    my_tup = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);
  }

};
```

the problem with either of these constructors is I dont know how to pass the template when creating the object if it is type auto like:

```
auto t1 = getMyTuple();
my_tuple_helper<???> mth(t1);
```

I had something that compiled that looked like this

```
template<typename T>
class my_tuple_helper
{
  public:
  T my_tup;

  my_tuple_helper(T t)
  {
    my_tup = t;
  }
};
```

and I could call

```
auto t1 = getMyTuple();
my_tuple_helper<decltype(t1)> mth(t1);
```

But I dont like the fact that T could be anything, Id rather have a std::tuple my_tup than a T my_tup(I'm not even sure if this would work).

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get a std::tuple which is stored into an auto object, into my helper class so that I can access it as a std::tuple object(in the class).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may do a function for that

```
template<typename... Args>
my_tuple_helper<Args...>
make_my_tuple_helper(const std::tuple<Args...>& tup)
{
    return my_tuple_helper<Args...>(tup);
}
```

And use it

```
auto t1 = getMyTuple();
auto mth = make_my_tuple_helper(t1);
```

Comment: Thank you I've never thought of this!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to make a factory method which deduces the template arguments for you. So you would make `my_tuple_helper` look like this:

```
template<typename... Args>
class my_tuple_helper
{
  public:
  std::tuple<Args...> my_tup;

  my_tuple_helper(std::tuple<Args...> t)
      : my_tup {std::move(t)}
  { }
};
```

Then write a factory method like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
my_tuple_helper<Args...> 
make_tuple_helper (const std::tuple<Args...>& t) 
{
    return { t };   
}
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c38a63da47198f6a)

Then if you want to output your tuple, you could do it in one call, like this:

```
auto t1 = getMyTuple();
std::cout << make_tuple_helper(t1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your demo was extremely helpful and fixed my problem :)